# How to call scene.view.paused just after the game is loaded in swift spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently  developing a swift spritekit game and wanted to make 
add a "Tap to Start" button that you will have to touch to start the game.
I wanted to add this feature since the game just starts right after transitioned to the GameScene, I want to give the user to tap this "Tap to start" instead of just starting instantly, so I was trying to add a `scene.view.paused = true` inside the didMoveToView and run the game when the "Tap to start " is pressed. The problem is when the script above inside didMoveToView method, the game wont load when transitioned. So how will I stop the game after being transitioned to the gameScene ? Since I'm new to swift and Spritekit , I would love to hear some tips and samples from you!

```
//var stopped : Bool = false
override var paused : Bool{
    didSet {
        if(stopped && !paused) { 
            paused = stopped
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to call the Pause method inside didMoveToView

Comment: Show your code what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to use the pause method

Answer (score 1):

The game won't load because `scene.view.pause = true` pauses everything, from actions to spawning in objects. The best way to achieve your goal is to create a non moving game and in the `touchesBegan()` method, start your game.(add the move actions to your objects). If this sounds to complicated, you can also pause all actions with: `self.speed = 0.0`. This pauses actions, **but does not pause spawning.**
If you still can't get it to work, post some more code and I will see what I can do to help you.